# Get url, query string and hash values

Tags: javascript

I have an input in which the user enters a valid url. I need to get the URL, query string (if the user enters) and hash (if the user enters) all separately.

So far I've done this:

```
  var url = input_value.split('?')[0]; //get url
  var qs = input_value.split('?')[1].split('#')[0]; //get query string value
  var hash = input_value.split('#')[1]; //get hash value
```

However, if the user doesn't enter any query string, just hash value, it throws an undefined error.

http://test.com/some-thing/ref?v1=obscurecode&something&else#1234

So for the url it should return: `http://test.com/some-thing/ref`

Query string: `?v1=obscurecode&something&else`

Hash: `#1234`

Comment: I believe I solved it. Do you wanna try my solution? And you don't need jQuery for this. This is just JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

It would be always better to use a `try` and `catch` block.

```
try {
  var url = input_value.split('?')[0]; //get url
} catch (e) {
  var url = input_value;
}
try {
  var qs = input_value.split('?')[1].split('#')[0]; //get query string value
} catch (e) {
  var qs = "";
}
try {
  var hash = input_value.split('#')[1]; //get hash value
} catch (e) {
  var hash = "";
}
```

This will help you to avoid any uncaught Type Errors. I have used `url = input_value`, in case there's no query string.

**Console Output**

[image: console]

And this is for your use case:

[image: use case]

Comment: In your console, hash is showing undefined if it's not entered.

Comment: I disagree HARD on the try catch blocks.. it makes javascript even slower and ahrder to read. Better check the length of the split yourself before getting an element from the array. WAY better practise to make your own validation instead of try/catch

Comment: @Nebulosar, I agree I ended up writing my own validation.